# How do I count relationships with a particular column value from an NSFetchRequest?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I currently have 2 entities:

- List
- Item

This is a one-to-many relationship, in which a List can have many Items.

Items have a column called `completed`.

I want to obtain the count of a Lists `completed` Items from my NSFetchRequest.

I know that I can simply do `List.Items.count` to obtain a count of ALL of a Lists Items, but I've no idea how to get the count of `completed` items as well.

How do I count relationships with a particular column value from an NSFetchRequest, or even some type of filter/where of `List.Items.count`?

## Edit

I had to rename `List` to `MyList` and `Item` to `MyItem`.

- MyList -> MyItem is one-to-many in Core Data (so I can use myList.myItems in the fetched results)
- MyItem -> MyList is many-to-one in Core Data (so I can use myItem.myList in the fetched results)

Here is how I fetch the data. First I use an extension:

```
extension MyList {
    static func getAllMyLists() -> NSFetchRequest<MyList> {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<MyList> = MyList.fetchRequest()
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "sortOrder", ascending: true)

        request.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

        return request
    }
}
```

Then I use a `@FetchRequest` in the view struct:

```
@FetchRequest(fetchRequest: MyList.getAllMyLists()) var myLists: FetchedResults<MyList>
```

Like I said I have no clue how to add the predicate I want to this so that the results include a count of the `completed` `MyItems`...I'm using a terrible approach in my answer by not utilizing the fetch request to its full potential due to lack of knowledge.

Comment: Use predicate..

Comment: On what? An expression? Like I said I have no clue how to do this.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean with a list that is completed? Is it a list where all items are marked as completed. Please add an example of what you want to do.

Comment: Items have a column called `completed` which is a boolean value. I want to have a count, per List, of the `completed` items in each list. This is a one-to-many relationship I set up in core data...

Comment: If you only want to count completed then you can use `filter` in your code, something like `lists.items.filter { $0.completed }.count`

Comment: Value of type 'NSSet.Element' (aka 'Any') has no member 'completed'. I definitely added this column to core data...

Comment: It's very hard to help you with that without seeing the actual code

Comment: You and dahiya were both correct, I posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

dahiya_boy and Joakim were both right in the comments, I had to use an `NSPredicate` with `filtered`:

```
let completedPredicate: NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "completed == true")
let completedCount = List.Items.filtered(using: completedPredicate).count
```

Comment: No, the comments mean to add the predicate to the fetch request. Filtering in the database is much more efficient.

Comment: Can you post an example as an answer of how I can do that and I'll accept it?

Comment: First *can **you** post* your code to fetch the data. Please edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

- If you have the reference to the `List` object just filter the `NSSet` relationship

  ```
  let numberOfCompletedItems = (list.items as! Set<MyItem>).filter{$0.completed}.count
  ```

  You can avoid the forced type cast if you declare the to-many relationship as native `Set<MyItem>`
- Otherwise fetch the items and add the predicate to the fetch request

  - `"TheList"` is the name of the list. If there is no `name` attribute use something unique.
  - `context` is the reference to the managed object context
  - It's assumed that there is a inverse relationship `list` in `MyItem`

    ```
    let listName = "TheList" 
    let request: NSFetchRequest<MyItem> = MyItem.fetchRequest()
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "list.name == %@ AND completed == true", listName)
    do {
       let completedItems = try context.fetch(request)
       let numberOfCompletedItems = completedItems.count
    } catch { print(error) }
    ```

And please name variables according to the naming convention starting with a lowercase letter

Comment: Is there a way to get all myLists with their `completed` myItem counts in a single fetch request? I was reading something about expressions but couldn't grasp how to predicate the expressions themselves...I'd like to spit out all of the lists in a `ForEach` and include the `completed` myItem counts for each...

Comment: Simple way: Fetch all **completed** items (remove `list.name == %@` in the predicate format) and group the array by `list` with `Dictionary(grouping:by:)`. `NSExpression` is also possible but this is a bit more complicated.